# MySQL JOIN very slow for no apparent reason

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-8.0

MySQL version 8.0.17:

```sql
SELECT b.ColB
FROM Table2 b
JOIN Table1 a ON a.ColA = b.ColA
WHERE b.ColB = 1234 -- some number
```

With the `JOIN`, this query takes about 2 seconds to run, without the JOIN it is almost instant. This is just a minimal example, the actual case requires the `WHERE` condition to cover multiple values (e.g. `WHERE b.ColB BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000`) - which takes a very very long time...

Structure of Table1 (irrelevant columns and indexes removed for brevity):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
  `ColA` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ColA`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=138221783 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Structure of Table2 (irrelevant columns and indexes removed for brevity):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Table2` (
  `ColA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ColB` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ColA`,`ColB`),
  KEY `FK_Table2_Table1_idx` (`ColA`),
  KEY `FK_Table2_Table3_idx` (`ColB`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Table2_Table1` FOREIGN KEY (`ColA`) REFERENCES `Table1` (`ColA`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

This is the CSV of the explain on this query:

```
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,rc,NULL,ref,"PRIMARY,FK_Table2_Table1_idx,FK_Table2_Table3_idx",FK_Table2_Table3_idx,4,const,607,100.00,"Using index"
1,SIMPLE,r,NULL,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,Table2.ColA,1,100.00,"Using index"
```

Some extra info running this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1` took 8.735 seconds and returned 1947948.

Running this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2` took 168.422 seconds and returned 19486319.

Why is the `JOIN` causing the query to run so very slowly?

Comment: You tell mysql to copare two big tabkes and check if any of the rows fit  togehter. First check with EXPLAIN if your query uses the right indexes. Second. reduce the number of rows by using your where clause directly on tabke b so that only a few rows have to bematched

Comment: The explain shows the right indexes, how do I move the where to table 2? I added the results of EXPLAIN to the question.

Comment: Hey.... why is Table3 in that explain???

Comment: because it can  be a candiadade for ina index

Comment: I believe it was using the wrong index!

Comment: Perfect when this solves your problem.

Comment: adding `use index (FK_Table2_Table1_idx)` didn't help...

Comment: After some thinking i  don't think that anything will help you besides descresing the number of rows see my answer. The problem starts with the composite key on table2 there is a index on that which would increase the speed when you ask for both  at the same time, further you have two more indexes that get carried around the hole time in my opinion you should redesign your table2 with an auto_incremnt  id column, and unique constraint on cola and colb and let the rest stand.  And see if this increases your speed

Answer (score 1):

If the only index is `PRIMARY KEY(colA, colB)` and the `WHERE` clause is testing `colB=constant`, then there is no usable index.

If this is a many-to-many mapping table you need to add `INDEX(colB, colA)` to allow for efficiently going from B to A.

Comment: There is an index on just `ColB`, called `FK_Table2_Table3_idx`

Comment: @AviadP. - How many rows have `b.ColB = 1234`?  Did the output have that many rows?

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the number of Rows that have to be joined reduce the number of rows as much as you can.

For your qiery

Use

```
SELECT b.ColB
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE ColB = 1234) b
JOIN Table1 a ON a.ColA = b.ColA
```

Instead of the SELECT * FROM Table2, you must use only the column that you actually need.

Comment: That reformulation does not help unless the derived table has a `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT`.